# Getting Error:The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error:

> **The given path's format is not supported.**

My code as follows:-

```
DOCon ObjDOCon = new DOCon();
ObjDOCon.DocName="Test Doc";
sPath="\\\\192.168.0.34\\Team\\Library\\Documents\\Test\\Docs\\Test.docx"
radUploadDoc.UploadedFiles[0].SaveAs(sPath, true); //rad telerik control
```

The code is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy it on server it is showing me error.
Please help, can't debug.

Thanks

Comment: Is `192.168.0.34` your production server's IP address? Sounds like you need to try `Path.Combine` or `Server.MapPath` for this issue.

Comment: While using Server.MapPath on my Local it is adding my Local Path